# PHP-парсинг

Tags: php

Всем привет. Хочу у вас узнать, как парсить страницу с помощью PHP. Приведу пример, как я, допустим, делал это на javascript:

```
var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    if (tmp[i].innerHTML == 'lol') {
        //.....
    }
}
```

Как мне сделать подобное только на PHP? Желательно не подключать библиотек...

Answer (score 2):

В PHP это не проблема, парсинг можно реализовать через: file_get_contents, curl, мульти curl и сокеты. Самыми простыми являются file_get_contents и curl.
Вот пример скрипта с file_get_contents и регуляркой:

```
$parser = file_get_contents("http://2ip.ru/index.php");
preg_match_all('#<big>([\d\.:]*)</big>#is', $parser, $stat);
foreach ($stat[1] as $ip) {

echo $ip;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сначала вытащить все содержимое страницы. Это можно сделать двумя способами:
1) Функция *file_get_contents(site)*. Но эта функция не сработает, например, для протокола *https*. В этом случае поможет cURL(проверьте, чтобы он был включен в PHP.ini):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin");
curl_exec($ch);
```

А уже после того, как получили содержимое страницы, можно пропарсить любыми функциями PHP, подходящие для парсинга.

Answer (score 1):

[Nokogiri](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110112/)

Answer (score 0):

Парсят в основном через регулярные выражения, но если документ имеет четкий DOM можно воспользоватся функциями обхода DOM

Comment: Ну мне просто нужно не одну строчку парсить, а весть файл.
На странице с каждого td тега буду собирать данные.

Comment: Так и я вам говорю не про одну строчку а про страничку целеком) Лучше вам предоставить код странички - и то что вы хотите получитьь - тогда все ответы будут более информативны для вас

Comment: Ну кусок страницы выглядит примерно так:

    <div>
    текс текст текст...
    <tr><td>текст</td></tr>
    текст текст текст...
    <tr><td>текст</td></tr>
    и т.д.
    </div>
Нужно после каждого простого текста вцепить инфу и то что после него до следующего простого цвета. И там сного повторяем..